# Combining Group BY and multiple Counts per Result

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle and want a result to contain multiple counts based on values. For example:

```
SELECT p.name, count(f.id) as eaten_apples, count(f.id) as eaten_oranges
FROM food f, people p
WHERE f.pid=p.pid
AND f.id = 'apple' OR f.id = 'orange'
GROUP BY p.name;
```

Obviously having count(f.id) there twice will each yield the same result, but the desire is to have one count per type of food eaten. Apples and Oranges. The intended result might look like so:

```
[0] => 
  name : john
  eaten_apples:  3
  eaten_oranges: 1
[1] => 
  name : sam
  eaten_apples:  0
  eaten_oranges: 9
...
```

In other words, multiple counts per result. In this case, the number of food items that a person ate.

My query now returns two results per name, that I *could* combine outside of SQL, but I want one result per name from the SQL result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not customary to group like that in Oracle but it is still possible if you need to. Instead, a better practice and my suggestion is to group by both `name` and `id` yielding two rows, one for each fruit.

```
SELECT p.name, f.id, count(1) as eaten_fruit
from food f, people p
WHERE f.pid=p.pid
AND (
       f.id = 'apple' OR 
       f.id = 'orange'
     )
GROUP BY p.name, f.id;
```

I believe that letting the application handle reading of the data above is more efficient, but as I pointed out, there are options for reformatting. There exist [a number of ways to transpose these row based results into columns](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm) and the other solution attempts one of them. My method of preference is to use the [PIVOT operator](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) that was specifically introduced for this purpose. To obtain the results, in the format you want, you can transpose the rows into columns as:

```
select name, id from
                     (
                       select p.name, f.id
                       from food f, people p
                       where f.pid = p.pid
                       and f.id in ('apple','orange')
                     )
pivot (
          count(id)
          for id in (
                      'apple' as eaten_apples,
                      'orange' as eaten_oranges
                    )
      );
```

It will work but is not customary.

Comment: Thanks, but I can get them in two rows now, but the application would work much better if done in one. I suppose it's too complex to do in Oracle, or rather, slow?

Comment: @lookingtolearn, I added to my answer a working solution but I am not sure if the application would work much better. A good db model shouldn't have to pivot or transpose in order to obtain results that the consuming application expects.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with ORA-00904: "id": invalid identifier. However, changing "select name, id" to "select *" made it work. I do not know why but ended up getting their via extensive trial-and-error. Again, thanks!

Comment: I don't see why. It should work as-is with explicit column names. But using `select  *` instead of `select name, id` will work as well for the specific problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option which will give the number of apples and oranges eaten per person in a single record:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT p.name, f.id
    FROM people p LEFT JOIN food f
        ON f.pid = p.pid
)

SELECT t1.name, COALESCE(t1.aCount, 0) AS eaten_apples,
    COALESCE(t2.oCount, 0) AS eaten_oranges
FROM people AS p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS aCount
    FROM cte
    WHERE id = 'apple'
    GROUP BY name
) AS t1
    ON p.name = t1.name
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS oCount
    FROM cte
    WHERE id = 'orange'
    GROUP BY name
) AS t2
    ON p.name = t2.name
```

Comment: Thanks, but I must be doing something wrong. Can you see why I might get "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"? I'm executing via PHP.

Comment: Without seeing your code it will be hard to debug this.  Can you try running this query directly in your Oracle first?